# Is it possible to return the name of a data frame in a list when passed to lapply?

Tags: r, split, lapply

I have a data frame with factors that I want to split and then apply a function to the data frame (ultimately using `purrr::map()`, by simplified in reprex with `lapply()`). When the data frame is split using multiple factors there are times when the data frame in the list is <0 rows>. In such instances, I would like to store the name of the list item so that I can return it. The behavior can be replicated by filtering a data frame to remove values with one of the factor levels. In the reproducible example below I want to capture "fizz" when <0 rows> ultimately to pass "fizz" to the message such that I can get a message that has `data frame fizz has 0 rows`.

```r
# create data frame
A = c(rep("foo", 3), rep("bar", 5), rep("fizz", 1))
B = 1:9
C = LETTERS[11:19]
df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)
df$A <- as.factor(df$A)

# show expected outcome on full data set 
mylist <- split(df, df$A)
names(mylist)
#> [1] "bar"  "fizz" "foo"

# desired outcome
myresult <- lapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {
  value_to_save <- unique(x$A)
  cat(paste0("data frame ", value_to_save, " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))
}
)
#> data frame bar has 5 rows 
#> data frame fizz has 1 rows 
#> data frame foo has 3 rows

# now subset to remove row with factor level == fizz
df <- df[df$A != "fizz", ]

# new list still has 3 elements but one has <0 rows>
(mylist <- split(df, df$A))
#> $bar
#>     A B C
#> 4 bar 4 N
#> 5 bar 5 O
#> 6 bar 6 P
#> 7 bar 7 Q
#> 8 bar 8 R
#> 
#> $fizz
#> [1] A B C
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $foo
#>     A B C
#> 1 foo 1 K
#> 2 foo 2 L
#> 3 foo 3 M

# names still exist in the list
names(mylist)
#> [1] "bar"  "fizz" "foo"

# same function obviously doesn't return a vector with "fizz"
# as mylist$fizz has no values to pass to unique()
# In this example I want "data frame fizz has 0 rows"
myresult <- lapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {
  value_to_save <- unique(x$A)
  cat(paste0("data frame ", value_to_save, " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))
  }
  )
#> data frame bar has 5 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame foo has 3 rows


# is there a function that I can use that is similar to 
# `.id =` option in `bind_rows` that appends the list item name to the data
# such that "fizz" could still be captured when <0 rows>?

newlist <- split(df, list(df$A, df$C))
# when returning to a dataframe with dplyr
df2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(newlist, .id = "id")
levels(df2$A)
#> [1] "bar"  "fizz" "foo"
df2
#>      id   A B C
#> 1 foo.K foo 1 K
#> 2 foo.L foo 2 L
#> 3 foo.M foo 3 M
#> 4 bar.N bar 4 N
#> 5 bar.O bar 5 O
#> 6 bar.P bar 6 P
#> 7 bar.Q bar 7 Q
#> 8 bar.R bar 8 R

# still no "fizz" results using this method either despite:
names(newlist)
#>  [1] "bar.K"  "fizz.K" "foo.K"  "bar.L"  "fizz.L" "foo.L"  "bar.M"  "fizz.M"
#>  [9] "foo.M"  "bar.N"  "fizz.N" "foo.N"  "bar.O"  "fizz.O" "foo.O"  "bar.P" 
#> [17] "fizz.P" "foo.P"  "bar.Q"  "fizz.Q" "foo.Q"  "bar.R"  "fizz.R" "foo.R"

# message output now has many empty names
myresult <- lapply(newlist, FUN = function(x) {
  value_to_save <- unique(x$A)
  cat(paste0("data frame ", value_to_save, " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))
}
)
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame foo has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame foo has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame foo has 1 rows 
#> data frame bar has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame bar has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame bar has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame bar has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame bar has 1 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows 
#> data frame  has 0 rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Updated with additional example**

The above reprex was a simplified example in hopes that there was a simple function (like the suggestion for deparse(substitute(x)) that I was missing. The following example provides a more realistic application where there is a function (i.e. `lm`) applied to the data and the function provides the user with a message indicating there were no values for the factor level.

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
library(purrr)
# create data frame
A = c(rep("foo", 3), rep("bar", 5), rep("fizz", 1))
B = 1:9
C = c("X", "X", "Y", rep("Y", 5), "Y")
df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)
df %>% mutate(A = as.factor(A), C = as.factor(C))
#>      A B C
#> 1  foo 1 X
#> 2  foo 2 X
#> 3  foo 3 Y
#> 4  bar 4 Y
#> 5  bar 5 Y
#> 6  bar 6 Y
#> 7  bar 7 Y
#> 8  bar 8 Y
#> 9 fizz 9 Y
complicated_function <- function(x) {
  if (nrow(x) >= 1) {
    value_to_print <-
      ifelse(length(unique(x$A)) == 1, 
             as.character(paste(unique(x$A), unique(x$C))), 
             "with multiple factors")
    cat(paste0("data frame ", value_to_print, " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))
    x$D <- x$B * 2 # imagine as a complicated process
    return(x)
  } else {
    cat("No data for this factor \n")
    return(x)
  }
}

df_processed <- complicated_function(df)
#> data frame with multiple factors has 9 rows

df %>% 
  split(list(.$A, .$C)) %>% 
  map(complicated_function) %>% 
  bind_rows() -> newdf
#> No data for this factor 
#> No data for this factor 
#> data frame foo X has 2 rows 
#> data frame bar Y has 5 rows 
#> data frame fizz Y has 1 rows 
#> data frame foo Y has 1 rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I would like the output to replicate the output for factor combinations where `<0 rows>` such that rather than a generic "No data for this factor" is replaced with "data frame fizz X has 0 rows".

Because the function is more complicated than just the original `cat()` example it is possible (and possibly both necessary and faster) to provide a summary message at the end of the function to report factors that has `<0 rows>`.

Comment: You can get the name of the object passed to a function using `deparse(substitute(x))`.  I wonder whether all you really need for this task is to pass the dataframe to `count()`. Maybe try `df %>% count(A)` in your first example?

Comment: `deparse(substitute(x))` are two functions I was unfamiliar with and I can see applications for them in the future. In this instance, the lapply (and subsequently in a pipe with split and map) x is returned as list notation not the list name. `x[[i]]`

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `mapply()` instead of `lapply` to pass the names and the list. Still not deriving the names from x, but it might work for your application:

```
myresult <- mapply(function(x, y) {cat(paste0("data frame ", y,
         " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))}, mylist, names(mylist))
# data frame bar has 5 rows 
# data frame fizz has 0 rows 
# data frame foo has 3 rows
```

Finally, since `lapply` does not pass the name along with x, you could attach it as an attribute to each list element:

```
for (i in seq(mylist)) attr(mylist[[i]], "name") <- names(mylist)[i]
myresult <- lapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {
   cat(paste0("data frame ", attr(x, "name"), " has ", nrow(x), " rows \n"))
   }
   )
# data frame bar has 5 rows 
# data frame fizz has 0 rows 
# data frame foo has 3 rows
```

Comment: this example relies on the anonymous function to call `mylist` from the global environment. I'm looking for a solution in the function that only depends on `x` as passed to the function. Example updated to show a more complete example use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem, trying to do a more advanced loop using apply. I've been using `for` loops instead and pass dataframe names when needed to a list vector that has all the names. Use the current loop iteration `i` to get the appropriate file name. Though it is not an elegant solution as people have been saying you don't need for loops.